# Form data not populating in API with POST request

Tags: javascript, forms, post, svelte

I am trying to submit a post request to an API in my svelte app. I am using the bind operator to bind the form data to the fields but when I hit submit the API is receiving the initial empty string values. How can I have the data input into the form populate in the API?

I am able to make post requests in Postman so I don't think there are any issues with the API

Here is my form component:

```
<script>
import { createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte'
import Button from '../shared/Button.svelte'

let dispatch = createEventDispatcher()
let opp = {title: '', opp_type: '', opp_description: '', more_info: ''}

const url = 'https://bchangeapi.herokuapp.com/opps';

// request options
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({opp}),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

// send POST request
fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res));

    const submitHandler = () => {
        console.log(opp)
        dispatch('add')
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={submitHandler}>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="title"> Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" bind:value={opp.title}>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="opp_type"> Opportunity Type:</label>
    <input type="text" id="opp_type" bind:value={opp.opp_type}>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="opp_description"> Opportunity Description:</label>
    <input type="text" id="opp_description" bind:value={opp.opp_description}>
</div>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="more_info"> More Info:</label>
    <input type="text" id="more_info" bind:value={opp.more_info}>
</div>
<Button type='secondary' flat={true}>Add Opportunity</Button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `fetch` request into `submitHandler`

```js
const submitHandler = () => {
  console.log(opp);
  dispatch("add");

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ opp }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  fetch(url, options)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

Comment: also move, building the `options` into the handler, otherwise it will just have the initial body